# O365 CLI Register Hubsite and get ID

Tags: powershell, hub-site, o365-cli

I am currently writing a script using the O365 CLI. The aim of the script is to register a site collection as a hub site. I am stuck at the end result of which I want to capture the ID.

The script so far does the following:

```
o365 spo login "https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com/" 
$hubsite = o365 spo hubsite register --url https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/hubsite 

Write-Host "Hubsite ID: $hubsite.ID"
```

It is a simple enough script however the "Write-Host" keeps returning blank. If I just enter $hubsite then I get the similar to the following:

> Description         : null
>   ID                  : 1af04d03-d2a9-4eb4-aa9c-000000
>   LogoUrl             : null
>   RequiresJoinApproval: false
>   SiteDesignId        : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   SiteId              : 1af04d03-d2a9-4eb4-aa9c-2acbfc952c00
>   SiteUrl             : https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/hubsite
>   Targets             : null
>   TenantInstanceId    : 35da7502-e9d2-4684-0000-d84b98b0000
>   Title               : Communication Site

Can please anyone help with where I am going wrong?

Comment: how about `Write-Host "Hubsite ID: $($hubsite.ID)" ? 
`

Comment: Unfortuantly this just output the below

Hubsite ID:

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by outputting the results to JSON, instead I now have the following:

```
o365 spo login "https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com/" 
$hubsite = o365 spo hubsite register --url https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/hubsite -output json | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Host "Hubsite ID: $hubsite.ID"
```